# How can I access constants in another file from my app.js file?

Tags: angularjs, angular-module, angular-config, angular-constant

I need a separate .js file which I can store in some constants.

I need to use the constants in this file in the app.js file.

The structure I am using for this and the mistake that I have encountered is like the one below.

What is the cause and solution of this problem for you? How can I best handle this situation? (doesnt matter 'value' or 'constant')

> "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: globalValueProvider <- globalValue <- AppController

**index.html**

```
<script src="app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script> //there it is

<script src="app/globalConstants.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app/globalValues.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var MyApp= angular.module("MyApp",
[
    //is necessary?
    //depency injection
    ...
]);
```

**const.js**

```
var MyApp= angular.module("MyApp");

MyApp.constant("globalConstant",
{
    "data": "test" // all data, source, file whatever u say that's all.        
});
```

**value.js**

```
var MyApp= angular.module("MyApp");

MyApp.constant("globalValue",
{
    "data": "test" // all data, source, file whatever u say that's all. 
});
```

**controller(in app.js)**

```
MyApp.controller("AppController",
[
    "$scope", "$rootScope", "globalValue", "globalConstant",
    function($scope,
        $rootScope,            
        globalValue,
        globalConstant) {
        debugger;
        console.log(globalValue);
        console.log(globalConstant);
    }
]);
```

Comment: dont use the angular tag in angularjs related questions

Comment: just edited, sorry my bad.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Any helping or ... ?

Comment: you inject `gloabalConfig` instead of `globalValue` in the controller. The strings must match the vars, in the correct order also

Comment: still same issue

Comment: sorry for the question but, do you source the files somehow?

Comment: Yes there are files in the files that should be accessed from within the app controller, not from the whole project.

Comment: do you source the other files in the html?

Comment: Not necessary i need access in app.js only. So, i dont use script tag to source them.

Comment: Ok to be able to _see_ any other file you need to source them, or preferably concat them to one big file (order matters) with a task runner, bundler whatever.

Comment: i need inter-file access in angularjs to get constant. i saw many answers but they didnt work. So, error in post. i need answer, if its possible.

Comment: I answered you, you NEED to source the files and then access them like you do. The files don't exist for the browser if not sourced. and the browser runs your code.

Comment: Post your index.html or your home page html code

Comment: The data I mentioned will not be displayed in the view related to the project. We are not a problem with .html's

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Check your view script tags. app.js must on top anothers. Thanks to @Mr_Perfect

Comment: Ok...I mean, I said it to you a multiple times, but noo let's thanks @Mr_Perfect :D , no hard feelings, it just funny